# Number of cycles taken by function

Tags: arm, cycle, timing, latency

I am using arm v7 how can i calculate total cycles taken by each function.Is there any way to calculate total cycles for entire function without knowing each instruction result latency.

Comment: Under what circumstances? For a highly deterministic single-task execution (probably with interrupts and/or caches disabled), possibly; for anything affected by the state of other tasks or the outside world (think caches, branch predictors, etc.), probably not. Alternatively if you only want an approximate figure then using the performance monitors to measure execution time over a reasonable number of profiling runs should give a fair average - it all rather depends on what exactly you're measuring and why.